# C# TcpListener Chrome issue

Tags: c#, google-chrome, tcplistener

I'm having an extrange issue when trying to do an HTTP GET request from Google Chrome.

I have a simple HttpServer as follows:

```
public class HttpServer
    {

    #region Attributes ----------------------------------------------------

    protected Int32 Port;
    private TcpListener listener;
    private Boolean closed;

    #endregion

    #region Properties (Own Members) --------------------------------------

    internal String Folder { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors --------------------------------------------------

    #endregion

    #region Methods (Own Members) -----------------------------------------

    public void Start(Int32 port, String folder)
        {
        if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
            throw new ArgumentException("folder");

        closed = false;

        this.Folder = folder;

        var ipLocal = IPAddress.Parse(NetUtils.GetLocalIPv4()); // My own stuff to get 
        this.Port = port;

        listener = new TcpListener(ipLocal, Port);
        listener.Start();

        StartAccept();
        }

    public void Stop()
        {
        if (listener == null) return;

        closed = true;

        listener.Stop();
        listener = null;
        }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
        if (closed) { return; }

        StartAccept();

        var client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);

        var processor = new HttpProcessor(client, this);
        processor.Start();
        }

    private void StartAccept()
        {
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptCallback, listener);
        }

    #endregion

    }
```

HttpProcessor is a class that manages data exchange between client and server and it's not the problem here.

I setup the server as normal:

```
var httpServer = new HttpServer();
httpServer.Start(localPort, "somepath");
```

Here comes the problem. **When I write on Mozilla Firefox "http://localIpAddr:localPort/somepath/somefile", it enters in AcceptCallback once (as expected) but writing the same url on Google Chrome results on calling that method twice.**

Can anyone explain me what's the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you look at the requests received. My guess is that one will be for an icon file or something similar.

Comment: I'm requesting audio files, for instance, "http://ip:port/file.wav". In fact in Firefox I can download the file properly, and in Chome the first call downloads the file but the second waits forever.  can't understand why is it called twice only on Chrome.

Comment: One of the connections is probably to be able to request `favico.ico` in parallell. Look at the URLs for the incoming requests. Either way, a HTTP client may open as many connections as they like.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to look further into the behaviour of chrome. This could be done using the application [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what web requests are being made by the browser.

You may also want to disable all extensions on the browser as these may also be making requests. Try also using a single instance of chrome with a single tab (this one is a long shot, but simply to eliminate any possibility of any inadvertent action taking place).